# String variable takes null value randomly after the first execution

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, string, null

In the first execution **checkNumber** takes the value from visualforce page properly.But after that sometimes **checkNumber** takes **null** value and shows the 'Please enter at least one search criteria' error message.Is there something wrong with my code and is there another reason for something like this to happen?

---

> Visualforce Page code block

```
<div class="slds-col">
                                <div class="slds-form-element">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--left slds-m-around--medium">
                                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-input__icon slds-icon-text-default">
                                            <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS103,'/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search')}"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        <input id="number" value="{!checkNumber}" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Check Number"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

---

---

> Controller

```
public String checkNumber { get; set; }
public List<DME_WrapperCheck> doGenerate() {

    system.debug('***checkNumber***'+checkNumber);

        //general query string for paid items without filter criteria by check date or number
        String queryString = 'SELECT Order__r.DME_Injury__r.Person__r.LastName, Order__r.DME_Injury__r.Person__r.FirstName, '
                        + 'Bill_Line_Item__r.Bill__r.ProviderInvoice__c, DOS_From__c, Product__r.ProductCode, Product__r.Name, '
                        + 'Quantity__c, Bill_Line_Item__r.Linecharge__c, Discount_Amount__c, APR__c, Bill_Line_Item__r.Name, '
                        + 'Bill_Line_Item__r.Denial_Reason__c, Bill_Line_Item__r.Bill__r.Id, Bill_Line_Item__r.Bill__r.Trading_Partner__r.Name, '
                        + 'Check_Number__c, Check_Paid_Amount__c, Check_Paid_Date__c, Bill_Line_Item__r.Bill__r.Trading_Partner__r.Id, '
                        + 'Bill_Line_Item__r.Bill__r.Trading_Partner__r.RA_Doc_Type_Preference__c, Bill_Line_Item__c, '
                        + 'Bill_Line_Item__r.Compliance_Reason__c, Bill_Line_Item__r.Duplicate_Check_Amount__c, Bill_Line_Item__r.Duplicate_Check_Number__c, '
                        + 'Bill_Line_Item__r.Bill__r.Trading_Partner__r.RA_Delivery_Preference__c, Bill_Line_Item__r.Reasoncode__c '
                        + 'FROM DME_Service_Item__c '
                        + 'WHERE (Paid__c = TRUE) AND (Check_Paid_Amount__c <> null AND Check_Paid_Amount__c <> 0 AND Check_Number__c <> \'\') '
                        + 'AND ';

        //append check date and number filter to query string
        if(this.checkDate != null) {

            if(this.checkNumber != '' && this.checkNumber != null) {

                queryString += '(Check_Paid_Date__c = ' + formattedStringDate + ' AND Check_Number__c = \''+ checkNumber + '\') ';
                run = true;

            } else {

                queryString += '(Check_Paid_Date__c = ' + formattedStringDate + ') ';
                run = true;

            }

        } else if(this.checkNumber != '' && this.checkNumber != null) {  

            queryString += '(Check_Number__c = \'' + checkNumber + '\') ';
            run = true;

        } else {

            showError = true;
            errorMsg = 'Please enter at least one search criteria';

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would have used [apex:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_input.htm) here; AFAIK a plain HTML `input` won't be bound to the controller field when the page is posted to the server.